# How to Remove Mask of JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I've a JFormattedTextField controlled by two RadioButton. In one of RadioButton I set the mask and the other I want to clear the mask and type normally. After set to type normally it doesn't return the value of `getText()`, the value only return if the mask is setted.

How could fix this problem ?

```
private void setMask() {
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
        txtPesquisar.setValue(null);
        if (rbNome.isSelected()) {
            //clear mask to type normally
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("****************************************");
            formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
        } else {
            //set mask
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##");
            formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
        }
        txtPesquisar.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter));
        txtPesquisar.requestFocus();
        txtPesquisar.selectAll();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you call `commitEdit()` on your JFormattedTextField before calling `getValue()`? If not, you will want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to call `commitEdit()` on your JFormattedTextField before calling getValue(). As per the [JFormattedTextField API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) section on `getValue()`:

> Returns the last valid value. Based on the editing policy of the AbstractFormatter this may not return the current value. The currently edited value can be obtained by invoking commitEdit followed by getValue.
>   Returns:

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestFormattedField extends JPanel {
    private JFormattedTextField txtPesquisar = new JFormattedTextField();
    private JRadioButton rbNome = new JRadioButton("None");
    private JRadioButton rbFormat = new JRadioButton("Format");

    public TestFormattedField() {
        txtPesquisar.setColumns(20);
        ButtonGroup btnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        btnGroup.add(rbFormat);
        btnGroup.add(rbNome);

        rbNome.setSelected(true);
        rbNome.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        rbFormat.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        add(txtPesquisar);
        add(rbFormat);
        add(rbNome);
        setMask();

        add(new JButton(new SetFormatAction()));
        add(new JButton(new GetTextAction()));
    }

    private void setMask() {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            txtPesquisar.setValue(null);
            if (rbNome.isSelected()) {
                //clear mask to type normally
                formatter = new MaskFormatter("****************************************");
                formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
            } else {
                //set mask
                formatter = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##");
                formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
            }
            txtPesquisar.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter));
            txtPesquisar.requestFocus();
            txtPesquisar.selectAll();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class SetFormatAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SetFormatAction() {
            super("Set Format");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setMask();
        }
    }

    private class GetTextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public GetTextAction() {
            super("Get Text");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_G);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final String text = txtPesquisar.getText();
            try {
                txtPesquisar.commitEdit();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                String title = "Incomplete Text Entry";
                String msg = "Text -- " + text + " is not yet complete";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestFormattedField.this, msg, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }  
            Object value = txtPesquisar.getValue();

            System.out.println("text: " + text);
            System.out.println("value: " + value);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestFormattedField mainPanel = new TestFormattedField();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JFormattedField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

In the future, please consider taking a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) since this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand your problem and then be able to help you. Please see my code as an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

on form constructor after inintcomponets

```
public Form1() {
 initComponents();
 MaskFormatter dateMask;
try {
 dateMask = new MaskFormatter("|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|");
 dateMask.install(JTEXTFORMATEE);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(Forma051.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```